# No response from Graph Item Analytics for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to get the number of views for Site Pages in SharePoint.
Using both of these Graph API calls, I get no response.

GET /sites/{site-id}/analytics

GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/analytics

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I found you can get analytics using the Drive URL for pages by appending /analytics/allTime.

You get the drive URL of a page from its .spItemUrl property.

E.g.

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/b!GnQp4DcoNU2ksI_fsAVecwcj-TlJ9UlNgrCloH1tyOFCOrcz0XSGSYgDTlNV8k0Z/items/01ODGPIZJINBXZI5RHGJGJEVZKMOGRERH6/analytics/allTime